# User defined order using EF and Postgresql

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have a category model class with category name, Id and admin order properties.

I want to provide an API endpoint to admin to reorder the categories as per his need.

I am not sure what is the most efficient way to tackle this using the EF Core and Postgresql (Core 2.2) - I'm a newbie to C# and .NET Core. Please correct me if my approach is wrong.

Here is what I tried:

My model class:

```
public class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int adminOrder { get; set; }
}
```

I have my service repository as below with `GetCategories` and `UpdateCategories` methods:

```
public class CategoryRepository: ICategoryRepository 
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _categoryContext

    public CategoryRepository(ApplicationDbContext categoryContext) 
    {
        __categoryContext = _categoryContext
    }

    public ICollection<Category> GetCategories() 
    {
        return _categoryContext.Categories.OrderBy(c=> c.Name).ToList();      
    }

    public bool UpdateCategoryOrder(Category category) 
    {
        _categoryContext.Update(category);
        return Save();
    }

    public bool Save() 
    {
        var changesMade = _categoryContext.SaveChanges();
        return changesMade >= 0 ? true : false;
    }
}
```

In my controller I am taking the list of categories in request body and comparing them with existing categories on field `adminOrder`.

If they are not equal I am updating the database

```
public IActionResult UpdateCategory([FromBody] List < Category > categoriesList) 
{
    var existingList = _categoryRepository.GetCategories();

    foreach(var cat in categoriesList) 
    {
        if (existingList.Where(c => c.Id == cat.Id && c.adminOrder != cat.adminOrder) 
        {
             _categoryRepository.UpdateCategory(cat) // since it returns true I can use if statement to check if it fails
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure it is the right way to do or not.

I went through few docs like

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/201898/user-defined-ordering-in-sql
- https://begriffs.com/posts/2018-03-20-user-defined-order.html

Not sure how to implement them in EF

Comment: Tip: Don’t use the Generic Repository anti-pattern with EF.

Comment: @Dai where do you see a generic repo here?!

Comment: @mahesh I'm not sure what your question is. Does your code work?

Comment: Yes @CaiusJard if it works is it the right way to do

Comment: I don't have a problem with the code as it stands; perhaps you could outline any specific concerns you have because questions like "this code works; is it good?" Aren't really on topic for SO.

Comment: @CaiusJard `CategoryRepository` and `ICategoryRepository` in the posted code. The Generic Repository pattern doesn't require the use of Generic types.

Comment: That's not a generic. This is standard "x implements Iy" probably for reasons of DI/IoC. I'd class `CategoryRepo:IRepo<Category>` as generic repository; this is  `CategoryRepo:ICategoryRepo`

Comment: @Mahesh do you want to implement sort/order by functionality? it is not clear from your question what you are looking for. you are asking to sort/order by but the code you have is for updating. please clarify your question

Comment: Yes I stated "I want to provide an API endpoint to admin to reorder the categories as per his need"  user defined sorting is what I am looking for using entity framework.
I am implementing it using the update method to update adminOrder. I can use sort on adminOrder later while getting the category items
My question is is it right way to implement it ? or is there a better way to implement user defined order

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly then pass parameters to the method using a parameter class with all the potential options for sorting. Something like public class CategoryParams{} then reference it in the where. .Where(c=>c.OrderField == CategoryParams.OrderField)